# replace random number of characters at random position with wildcard

Tags: java, regex, random

I am trying to create a program which would replace random number of characters at random position with "*". Star is letter used in main program and it is replaced with "." a wildcard to matches any possible result.

So far I manage to create the code you see bellow. It replaces exactly 1 character of specific word.
Any help from here on now would be much appreciated.

**EXAMPLE:**

Input word: MOUSE

RANDOM GENERATOR for how much characters to replace: 3

RANDOM GENERATOR at which places to replace: 1, 3, 5

RESULT: *O*S*

```
public class random_2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test;
    int dolzina = 0;
    String outputFile = "random_2.txt";
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();

    try {

        File file = new File("random1.txt");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        String vrstica;
        while ((vrstica = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

            list.add(vrstica);
            // dolzina=list.size();
            // System.out.println(dolzina);

        }

        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(outputFile);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
        for (int idx = 0; idx <= list.size(); ++idx) {
            test=list.get(idx);
            dolzina=test.length();

            Random rGenerator = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i<= dolzina; ++i) {
                int randomInt = rGenerator.nextInt(dolzina);
                StringBuilder beseda = new StringBuilder(test);
                beseda.setCharAt(randomInt, '*');
                System.out.println(beseda);
                dolzina=0;
        }}

        System.out.println("Done.");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified your code and its working:

```
try {

        File file = new File("random1.txt");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        String vrstica = bufferedReader.readLine();
        while (vrstica != null) {

            list.add(vrstica);
            vrstica = bufferedReader.readLine();
            // dolzina=list.size();
            // System.out.println(dolzina);

        }

        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(outputFile);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);

        for (int idx = 0; idx < list.size(); ++idx) {
            test = list.get(idx);
            dolzina = test.length();

            Random rGenerator = new Random();
            StringBuilder beseda = new StringBuilder(test);

            for (int i = 0; i < dolzina; ++i) {
                int randomInt = rGenerator.nextInt(dolzina);

                beseda.setCharAt(randomInt, '*');
                System.out.println(beseda);

            }
            out.print(beseda);
            out.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
String mask(String s, int charsToMask){
  if(s.length() < charsToMask) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

  List<Integer> shuffle = new ArrayList<>(s.length())
  for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    shuffle.add(i, i);
  }
  Collections.shuffle(shuffle);
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s)
  for (int i = 0; i < charsToMask; i++) {
    sb.setCharAt(shuffle.get(i).intValue(), (char)'*')
  }
  return sb.toString()
}

print mask("MOUSE", 3)
```